# Filter out objects in an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

I've got `var campaigns: [Campaign] = []`
Campaign objects have a property `published`.
I'd like to map through the array and filter out unpublished campaigns so that the result is an array holding published campaigns only
I've tried below but get of course get `'nil' is incompatible with return type 'Campaign'`

```swift
self.campaigns = self.campaigns.map({ (campaign) -> Campaign in
                        if campaign.published == 1 {
                            return campaign
                        } else {
                            return nil
                        }
                    })
```

Anyone knowing the solution to this mini-problem?
Thanks ;-)

Comment: If your goal is to filter `self.campaigns`, why don't you call `filter`? Is there some good reason why you cannot call it? `self.campaigns = self.campaigns.filter {$0.published == 1}` or whatever

Comment: It's ironic that you have mentioned the word `filter` in your question and you are not using it. Try what @matt said, if it still didn't work do share the `Object` and we will help you figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it your way you'd need to use `compactMap` in order to drop the nil responses, however you'd be better off just using `filter`

```
campaigns = campaigns.filter{$0.published == 1}
```

Comment: this ^  `map` should really only be used when changing the type. `compactMap` is kind of like a `map` + `filter` so not preferred since the resulting type is the same in your example

Comment: There is a mutating method called `removeAll(where:)` on `RangeReplaceableCollection` exactly for that. `campaigns.removeAll { $0.published != 1}`

Comment: Thanks @flanker for the solution. Got so stuck with map that I didn't consider to look for other functions to solve my problem :-(

Comment: Thanks @Leo Dabus for the alternative approach!!

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @flanker answer
Use `compactMap` that returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

```
self.campaigns = self.campaigns.compactMap({ $0.published == 1 ? $0 : nil })
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because the result of `compactMap` is an array of `Bool` (and after the edit an array of `Int`)

Comment: Nope, `compactMap` is wrong anyway, it transforms the type to another. The returned type of the closure must be `Campaign `, It works with `{ $0.published == 1 ? $0 : nil}` but this is a cumbersome version of `filter`.